# Feedback association between two rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models - `Customer` and `Contractors`. I have setup a simple app, where they interact on an `activity`. Now at the end of it, I would like for them to leave each other feedbacks. Nothing complex just a database field of `comment`.

I am wondering what is the right model association to have here?

Thanks

Comment: `Comment` should belong to `Customer` or `Contractor` ?

Comment: Well i was thinking more of a `feedback` model. So `comment` is only one field. If need more fields can be added to it later. That being said, a `Customer` can leave a comment for `Contractor` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Customer 
  has_many :feedbacks
end

class Contractor
  has_many :feedbacks
end

class Feedback
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :contractor
end
```

It just looks like a many-to-many join table except and unless you want to access the contractors that a customer left feedback for and viceversa the `has_many :contractors/:customer, :through => :feedbacks` is removed.

The Feedback table would need to have the ids of the customer and contractor that it belongs to etc. If you need more help/explanation let me know through comment.

Comment: i had a similar thing in mind. Just a matter of implementing it. Let me try it out tomorrow and see how that works. thanks :)